# TextBox with single line WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm using WPF.
I try to create single line TextBox not multi line.

What i'm trying is

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBox Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Single line" />
</StackPanel>
```

But when i tried to enter a text, the TextBox is multiline and not single line
How can i fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per default the Textbox is singleline. Maybe you have defined some Style for Textbox?

Try to set **TextWrapping="NoWrap"** and **AcceptsReturn="False"** for your TextBox